# How to transform (rotate) this hyperbola?

Tags: matrices, geometry, analytic-geometry, transformation, rotations

Given this hyperbola $x_1^2-x_2^2=1$, how do I transform it into $y_1y_2=1$?

When I factor the first equation I get $(x_1+x_2)(x_1-x_2)=1$,

so I thought $y_1=(x_1+x_2)$ and $y_2=(x_1-x_2)$. Therefore the matrix must be $
\begin{pmatrix}
1&1\\1&-1
\end{pmatrix}
$.

But in maple it is just drawn as a straight line. However, it should be a rotated hyperbola.

Is my matrix incorrect? And how come $x_1^2-x_2^2=1$ is a hyperbola and $(x_1+x_2)(x_1-x_2)=1$ is a line? Aren't these equations equivalent?

[image: Screenshot]
[image: Screenshot2]

Comment: $(x_1 + x_2)(x_1 - x_2) = 1$ is not a line, it is hyperbola. You definitely did something wrong in Maple. [Here's](http://bit.ly/1JkQ6iA) what WA says.

Comment: @Kaster Here's what I typed in: "implicitplot((x+y)(x-y) = 1, x = -10 .. 10, y = -10 .. 10, grid = [200, 200], style = surface)"

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the output?

Comment: @Kaster  I posted a screenshot.

Comment: The first screenshot looks more like $x-y = 1$ than $(x+y)(x-y) = 1$.

Comment: I never used maple, so can't say for sure, but maybe you need multiplication symbol or take the expression in parens, or maybe both?

Comment: @Kaster The multiplication symbol did the trick.