# Why does this hyperboloid change into a surface?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, transformation, quadratics, quadrics

Given this equation $x^2+y^2+z^2+2xy+2xz+2yz-x-y-z=6$ and the corresponding quadric:

[image]

If I rearrange the equation to $(x+y+z-3)(x+y+z+2)=0$ (which is equivalent), I get:

[image]

So, which is the right quadric to my equation? Why does it have two representations?

Comment: Your code for the first expression has a typo; the `x*y` term appears twice.

Comment: @VictorLiu Thanks, my mistake. But then it yields two parallel planes. Why is in the second drawing only one plane?

Comment: The correct surface is two parallel planes. I don't know why in one case it would plot only one plane; that may be an artifact of the software you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as in your question [How to transform (rotate) this hyperbola?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1343745/how-to-transform-rotate-this-hyperbola), it appears you've omitted the multiplication symbol between the parenthesized factors in the second plot.